# Php_exel_reader как определить принадлежность строки таблицы xls к группе

Tags: php, xls

Здравствуйте!
Есть прайс в xls формате. В нем строки объединены в группы (плюсики/минусики слева от таблицы). Как определить, что строка это группа и принадлежность строки группе?

Comment: Смотрите методы библиотеки через которую общаетесь с форматом

Comment: Смотрел. Но ничего на мой взгляд не нашел. Даже больше: есть метод, который выводит получаемую классом скрипта структуру xls с данными в объекте. Но там тоже ничего похожего нет, кроме бинарного или закодированного свойства data.

Comment: Ну тогда, как вариант, используйте условия группировки, если конечно они явные.

Comment: Именно поэтому и спрашиваю, т.к. сожалению прайс сделан криво в отношении группировок